# Best way to parameterize a method

Tags: dll, binding, snmp

I'm writing a custom dll that references [another dll](https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib) to implement SNMP PDUs.

Now in my dll I need to implement the Binding, that is the possibility to select from which network card to instantiate the udp packet towards the snmp agent. This function is not present in the dll that I downloaded, therefore I have to insert it by hand. The github module is somewhat extensive, there are several encapsulated methods, and the package instance is created within a series of encapsulations , here is the code that does it:

```
udpSocket.SendTo(bytes, receiver);
udpSocket.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
```

Before the two instructions above, I have to add these 3 lines for binding:

```
IPAddress Binding = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.195"); 
IPEndPoint localIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(Binding, 0); 
udpSocket.Bind(localIPEndPoint);
```

Now what I need to do is pass the address (192.168.1.195) as a parameter. My question is: is there a transversal way to declare some kind of global variable in the dll project, considering that the class implementing the method is static?

Comment: "This function is not present in the dll that I downloaded", what function? UDP does not require any "binding".

Comment: @Lex Li Yes i know but for technical reasons i need it.